# how to secure html page with simple javascript code?

Tags: passwords, locking, prompt

I need a simple javascript code that I'll put inside the html page and do the following:

When a user enters the page, a popup appears that asks to enter a password.
If the correct password is entered, the user will see the window content.

If the wrong password is inserted, the popup will say: "wrong password, try again"

And if a user hit the "cancel" button,
it will do nothing, and the page will stay blank without content until the user hits the refresh button or the back button to the previous page and will try to enter the "secure" page again,

It doesn't need to be complicated or too secured.
The content of the page that I want to secure is not sensitive.

thanks.

Comment: This is pointless, as JS is evaluated on the client. He already has the page, and can decide to simply not run the Javascript at all.

Comment: this page created for users with no knowledge of javascript so it'll still be fine for me.. can you make a little code for me? it'll really help me
thank you very much.